# determine the size of placeholder to match the actual size of the image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to load images from internet but i want to show a placeholder till load finishes.
How can i determine the size of placeholder to match the actual size of the image?
The width and height of the image from the api are 2000, 3000 respectively. How can I convert these values?

Comment: Do you know the size before hand? I do not think you can figure out the size of the image before you are able to load it

Comment: The api provides the image width and height for example 2000w, 3000h

Comment: I dont know how to use these values

Comment: Ok, I will try to answer the question. Do you need sample code? I can tell you the needed classes

Comment: It doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to the question,

First, you should download an image the from the web through one of many methods.

1. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html
2. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html
3. get the bytes and convert to an image with this https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html

Here are the widgets you should use.

You should use this widget as a sized placeholder.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html

Here is a possible child to show a loading animation

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html

To display it, you can either complete the FutureBuilder or

```
Image im = null;
Map imageDimensions = null;
initState(){
    fetchImageDimension.fetch().then((imageD) => setState(){imageDimensions = imageD;})
    somefuntion.fetch().then((image) => setState(){im = image;})
}

Widget build(buildContext context){
   var width =  imageDimensions["width"];
   var height = imageDimensions["height"];
   var placeholderColor = imageDimensions["color"];
   var dimensionsLoaded = imageDimensions != null;
   var imageLoaded = im != null;
   return if(imageLoaded)
      Image..... 
     else {
         if(dimensionsLoaded) {
             SizedBox(
               width: width,
                height: height,
                child: const Card(child: Container(color: Color(placeholderColor)),
             )
         } else {
             //neigher image or dimensions are Loaded. Nothing you can do
         }
     }
  }

}
```

This code is not meant to be compiled but it is meant to show the possible options to answer the question.

Comment: Which part? You are asking how to make a placeholder widget. You provided no information on the api etc

Comment: "width": 5245,
"height": 3497,
"color": "#60544D", this is part of the API response, i need a way to utilize these values

Comment: ok I will edit my response. Most of my answer will be the same

Comment: Man!, i can not use the width and height of 5245,3497 inside flutter, i`m asking for a way to convert these values to be able to use them

Comment: Dude, you keep making revisions to your question. Sized box should accept doubles and floating point numbers

Comment: i know that, i mean that the height of 3497 is very big. the api provides it as pixels but i`m asking for how to convert this value

Comment: Do you want to scale your image?
If so, you probably will not care about grabbing the image size at all. You just scale it to the space you provide.